# rdlc report print button is hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, rdlc, reportviewer

Print button is hidden in microsoft rdlc report in browser IE/Chrome etc.

How to make it visible?

I tried to enable from installing Microsoft report viewer redistributable 2012, 2014 with sp1, sp2 and enabled options from report viewer designer also but not succeeded. Anyone can help me out please?

Print button is invisible:

[image: print button is invisible]

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/182778/RDLC-ReportViewer-Print-Button-not-working-in-IE10-and-IE11-browsers/) article and update your question providing more information.

Answer (score 1):

> ReportViewer client printing feature relies on ActiveX which is not supported by any browser except IE 9 (or earlier), that's why you do not get print button when Chrome, Firefox or IE10/11 browser is involved. For printing, you should export to PDF and let the user to print it. That's the "manual" approach. If you are able to write some .NET code, then you can do that programatically as described here or do it by yourself.

Have a look at [ASP.Net forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/1962293.aspx?+Report+Viewer+print+Button+missing+from+browser).